# Javascript constructor, prototype and instantiation. Architecture and Framework

Tags: javascript, architecture, frameworks, constructor, prototypal-inheritance

I'm developing a "framework" and find myself at writing modules.

for each module exists a set of common initialization rules and common set of functions.

STEP 1. constructor function:

```
var ns = "namespace1";
t.scenarios[ns] = function (container, instanceName, options) {
    // common for all scenarios, e.g. options initialization
    t.core.defaultScenarioConstructor(this, ns, container, instanceName, options)

    // things only for NAMESPACE1
    this.PROPERTY1 = 1;
}
```

**STEP 2.** (question related)
then I have a prototype

```
var p = t.scenarios[ns].prototype;

p.newfunction = function(){
    this.PROPERTY1; // accessible
}
```

which gets filled with THINGS_ONLY_FOR_NAMESPACE1

```
t.core.defaultScenarioPrototype(p);
```

STEP 3 / 4.
instantiate class (with new keyword) & call dom builder

```
p.initNewView = function(container) {/* build dom and assign handlers*/}
```

Now the question... I would like to do common constructor/prototype initialization within the other "core" module. If on STEP 2 we add functions to prototype then they have "this" keyword and can access CURRENT_INTANCE fields, e.g. PROPERTY1.

If however the prototype is passed as a variable to "defaultScenarioPrototype" builder, then all functions have the other "this" of CORE class, where lives the builder.

How should we add "common" functions to a prototype from another module?

Comment: Is `t.core.defaultScenarioPrototype.call(this,p);` not working? You can use call or apply for inheriting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Comment: @HMR, many thanks I'll check it. Not yet that ken with call & apply.

Comment: @HMR post it as an answer, please, that's very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested I'll add my comment as an answer. To call a function within a certain `this` context you can use [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Bind is used a lot in cases where you pass a callback and don't want to use closures:

```
setTimeout(myOjbect.somefunction,100);//this in somefunction is window

setTimeout(function(){
  myObject.somefunction();
},100);//this in somefunction is myObject but a closure is created

setTimeout(myObject.somefunction.bind(myObject),100);//this is myObject 
                                    //and no closure is created
```

One would assume that bind uses less memory and is faster but I recently read somewhere that bind is actually slower than passing a closure so I'm not sure about the memory consumption either.